# Python program to find if a certain keyword is present in a list of documents (string)

Tags: python

**Question:** A researcher has gathered thousands of news articles. But she wants to focus her attention on articles including a specific word.

The function should meet the following criteria:

Do not include documents where the keyword string shows up only as a part of a larger word. For example, if she were looking for the keyword “closed”, you would not include the string “enclosed.”

She does not want you to distinguish upper case from lower case letters. So the phrase “Closed the case.” would be included when the keyword is “closed”

Do not let periods or commas affect what is matched. “It is closed.” would be included when the keyword is “closed”. But you can assume there are no other types of punctuation.

**My code:-**

```py
keywords=["casino"]
def multi_word_search(document,keywords):
    dic={}
    z=[]
    for word in document:
        i=document.index(word)
        token=word.split()
        new=[j.rstrip(",.").lower() for j in token]
        
        for k in keywords:
            if k.lower() in new:
                dic[k]=z.append(i)
            else:
                    dic[k]=[]             
    return dic
```

It must return value of `{'casino': [0]}` on giving `document=['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car', 'Casinoville?']`, `keywords=['casino']`, but got `{'casino': []}` instead.
I wonder if someone could help me?

Comment: Please edit your question so the example is properly displayed.

Comment: Is the use of python mandatory ? Using `grep -i '\bclose\b' path_to_file/*.txt` should work fairly nicely. `'\b'` represent a word boundary in regexp.

Comment: It has to be done using python.

Answer (score 1):

I would first tokenize the string "new" using split(), then build a set to speed up look up.

If you want case insensitive you need to lower case both sides

```
for k in keywords:
   s = set(new.split())
   if k in s:
      dic[k] = z.append(i)
   else:
      dic[k]=[]
return dic
```

Comment: The `else` branch is doint nothing, you should remove it completely...

Answer (score 0):

This is not as trivial as it seem. From a NLP (natural language processing) splitting a text into words is not trivial (it is called tokenisation).

```py
import nltk

# stemmer = nltk.stem.PorterStemmer()

def multi_word_search(documents, keywords):
    # Initialize result dictionary
    dic = {kw: [] for kw in keywords}
    for i, doc in enumerate(documents):
        # Preprocess document
        doc = doc.lower()
        tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(doc)
        tokens = [stemmer.stem(token) for token in tokens]
        # Search each keyword
        for kw in keywords:
            # kw = stemmer.stem(kw.lower())
            kw = kw.lower()
            if kw in tokens:
                # If found, add to result dictionary
                dic[kw].append(i)
    return dic

documents = ['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car', 'Casinoville?' 'Some casinos']
keywords=['casino']
multi_word_search(documents, keywords)
```

To increase matching you can use stemming (it removes plurals and verbs flexions, ex: running -> run)

Comment: I'm not aware about the use of nltk library, could you please provide an easy approach to the problem?

Comment: [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) is a library that ease natural language processing. Here it is used to split a document in words (a simpler approach is to segment on whitespaces `document.split(' ')`). `nltk.word_tokenize` deals with sentences such as `"It is the casino's!"` which is segmented in `['It', 'is', 'the', 'casino', "'s", '!']` instead of `['It', 'is', 'the', "casino's!"]`.

Comment: could you please brief me, how tokenize is working, 'cause I'm a bit confused?

Comment: Basically, many regular expressions are applied to the text to account for different segmentation problem, there would be one that replaces `!` by ` ! `, then `'s` by ` 's` and such. And then split on whitespace to get a list of words. See [here](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/6532301-introduction-to-natural-language-processing/7108031-apply-tokenization-techniques) if you want more information.

Comment: pretty much clear now... The resource is quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

This should work too..

```
document=['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car', 'Casinoville?']
keywords=['casino', 'car']

def findme(term):      
    for x in document:
        val = x.split(' ')
        for v in val:
            if term.lower() == v.lower():
                return document.index(x)
    
for key in keywords:
    n = findme(key)
    print(f'{key}:{n}')
```